# Как посчитать контрольную сумму бд?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

Есть приложение под андройд, которое использует SQLite бд. И есть сервер на java, работающий с MySQL.
Необходимо узнать одинаковые ли в этих двух базах данные.
Решил использовать конрольные суммы для этого.
Как реализвать это средствами Java?

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ очень высокоуровневый, потому что задача довольно обширная.*

### Это плохая идея, но уж если делать...

Встроенных механизмов в самих БД для этого нет.

Поскольку контрольные суммы обычно определяются для последовательностей байт, ваша задача получить одинаковые последовательности байт из одинаковых байт на разных БД. Каждая такая последовательность должна **уникально** идентифицировать текущее состояние данных.

А хэширование (снятие контрольной суммы) в этом контексте будет лишь своеобразным алгоритмом сжатия (с потерями) этой последовательности. Поскольку есть потери, он будет **не в состоянии *доказать* идентичность данных** из-за ненулевой (хоть и очень небольшой) вероятности коллизий.

В Java есть [класс `MessageDigest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html). Можно инициализировать его объект и кормить его методу `update` отдельные небольшие массивы байт данных, кусочки описанной выше последовательности, получая их по кусочкам (курсором или иным образом) из базы, чтобы не хранить в памяти целиком.

Сам алгоритм получения уникальной последовательности это целое поле для творчества, поэтому готовый код приводить не буду. Но на этом поле есть некоторые мины и грабли, о которых считаю нужным упомянуть:

- Упорядочивайте данные по первичному ключу. БД, скорее всего, и так это сделает, но лучше сделать это явно и обезопасить себя от внезапных багов.
- Проверьте, что кодировки данных совпадают.
- Нужно аккуратно показывать в массиве байт границы отдельных полей, записей и таблиц, чтобы не получилось так, чтобы похожие, но разные наборы данных представились одинаковыми массивами.

  - Такое запросто может быть, если, скажем, просто дампать значение за значением подряд (фактически конкатенируя их). Это может неплохо работать на практике, но может сломаться в самый неподходящий момент.
- Не используйте "резиновые" форматы вроде JSON, для которых разные реализации маршаллеров на одинаковых данных могут выдавать разные вещи. Или хотя бы используйте одинаковые предсказуемые реализации.

---

...а может статься, **разумнее воспользоваться другим хранилищем данных**. Например, каким-нибудь, в котором изначально предусмотрена раздельная работа отдельных БД и синхронизация "когда-нибудь потом". Ведь с высокой вероятностью вас интересует не только проверка на идентичность данных, но и приведение их в идентичный вид.

Например, есть совместимые (на большой процент) между собой CouchBase для Android, CouchDB для сервера и PouchDB для браузера. Но если поискать, могут найтись какие-нибудь ещё.